# How do you detect a square bracket in a KeyDown or KeyUp WPF event?

Tags: c#, wpf, keyboard, wpf-controls

I'd like to detect if a keystroke would result in a closing [square bracket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket#Square_brackets_.5B_.5D) `]` in a `KeyDown` event of a WPF `Popup`:

```cs
private void MyPopup_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (theKeyStrokeWouldResultIsAClosingSquareBracket)
    {
        // ...
        // do stuff
        // ...
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

The solution has to work for any keyboard layout. Notice that key mappings of different layouts usually differ quite a lot. Therefore checking for the right key combination (like `Ctrl + Alt + Digit 9` on a German [QWERTZ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QWERTZ) keyboard or simply `OemCloseBrackets` on a US [QUERTY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QWERTY) keyboard) is unfortunately no solution.

How can you accomplish such a detection despite these problems?

---

**EDIT - Adding some information before starting the bounty:**

I'm currently implementing an IntelliSense-like function in my current project. The IntelliSense stuff is inspired by this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22803/Intellisense-like-Method-Selection-Pop-up-Window

The custom syntax allows expressions like `[abc].[def] > [ghi].[jkl]`, where an user should be able to make the intellisense function autocomplete the text in the brackets. To make the intellisense  function a bit more similar to Visual Studio's (and lots of other IDEs') behavior, I'd like to enable the user to type a closing square bracket in the popup's list box to force an autocomplete.

Comment: Have you tried `if (e.KeyCode == Keys.OemCloseBrackets)` ?

Comment: Yes. However, as I wrote in the question, this is specific to the US QWERTY layout (and similar layouts) and does not work with other layouts that differ from that keyboard in this regard.

Comment: Maybe you should listen for the TextInput instead of trying to deal with KeyDown so you don't need to handle the keyboard translation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the `PreviewTextInput` event - this gets a `TextCompositionEventArgs` argument whose `Text` property will be the closing bracket.

Comment: Okay, that was pretty easy after all. Thanks a lot for the hint!

Answer (score 2):

You could add a transparent `TextBox` to the popup, and subscribe to the `TextChanged` event on that instead of an event on the `Popup`.

Comment: Though this sounds a bit dirty, it would actually help. Thanks for this suggestion. I'll wait for some other answers before accepting this answer though.

Comment: Definitely dirty :)  My experience is more with Silverlight than WPF, but I liken it to Breaking Bad.  First, everything is nice and rosy, but the further you get, the more dirty tricks you need to rely on in order to work around the limitations of life.

Comment: +1 sometimes you gotta do what you gotta do! Simple, cheep/easy to implement.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a key combination I don't think you'll be able to capture it using a key down event.

if (e.Key == Key.OemCloseBrackets)
{

}

is the correct approach for the simple case with an English keyboard. If you would like to cope with the German keyboard that you have described, you should do a string comparison on the text box that you are working with calling from the key up event.

if (txtKeypad.Text.Substring(txtKeypad.Text.Length - 1, 1) == "]")

I hope this helps.

Ed

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. Unfortunately, I don't have `TextBox` that I'm working with. The event handler sits directly in the Popup. And the Popup does not contain any control with user-editable text.

Comment: txtKeypad.Text.EndsWith("]") would be simpler. Your code will also need check for .Lenght > 0